# Calculate 3D triangle area by determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, euclidean-geometry

It is well known that the area of the triangle (with vertices $a, b, c$) can be calculated as

$ \frac{1}{2}\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} a - c \\ b - c \end{bmatrix}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} a_x - c_x, a_y - c_y \\ b_x - c_x, b_y - c_y \end{bmatrix}\right)$

But what if I want to calculate the area of a triangle in 3 (or any higher) dimensions?

I tried to extend the matrix as $ \begin{bmatrix} a_x - c_x, a_y - c_y, a_z - c_z \\ b_x - c_x, b_y - c_y, b_z - c_z \\ 1, 1, 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $ \begin{bmatrix} a_x - c_x, a_y - c_y, a_z - c_z \\ b_x - c_x, b_y - c_y, b_z - c_z \\ 0, 0, 1 \end{bmatrix}$ but I got incorrect results.

I'm not interested in solutions involving cross products.

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleArea.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is equal to
$$
\frac12\sqrt{\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} a_x - c_x, a_y - c_y, a_z - c_z \\ b_x - c_x, b_y - c_y, b_z - c_z \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_x - c_x, a_y - c_y, a_z - c_z \\ b_x - c_x, b_y - c_y, b_z - c_z \end{bmatrix}^T\right)},
$$
where $T$ denotes transposition.

Comment: Could you provide a proof of your formula ?

Comment: @JeanMarie How can we show that the volume is given by the absolute value of the determinant? The same answer here: we should check the axioms of volume, namely multiplication by scalars, sums of vectors, and normalization. But really the square root is simply the $2$-norm coming from the canonical inner product on the space of alternating forms.

Comment: I just realized that the quantity inside the square root of your formula is :$det\begin{pmatrix}\vec{CA}^2&\vec{CA}.\vec{CB}\\ \vec{CB}.\vec{CA}&\vec{CB}^2\end{pmatrix}=\|\vec{CA}\|^2\|\vec{CB}\|^2(1-cos^2(\theta))$ which is indeed equivalent to the formula obtained through the cross product.

Comment: Great, I like your proof better than mine. But the OP did eliminate explicitly cross products  in his question, and so I also did, on purpose.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ah, forgot to mention, my answer extends easily to the $k$-volume determined by $k$ vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ with $k\le n$.

Comment: Yes, and this is indeed very interesting because cross-products don't exist outside $\mathbb{R^3}$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Actually, cross products do exist in any $n$ dimensions ($n > 0$) as the Hodge dual of the wedge product of $n-1$ vectors. Your solution generalizes this way, by $\frac{1}{n!} |\star(v_0 \wedge v_1 \dots)|$

Comment: @JohnB Yeah, I was looking for a solution which generalizes to arbitrary simplex and dimensions. It turns out that your solution is computationally  more efficient from dimension 4, while the cross product variant is numerically more stable.

Comment: @plasmacel I do agree for the use of the Hodge star. About numerical stability, unless the dimension is high, is it a concern ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Well, if at least one of the coordinates is higher, the calculation of the determinant before the square root can easily exceed the precision of single precision floating-point numbers. So you can end up with error $\delta_{error} > 1$. With double precision there is no such error. I tried with $(100,100,0), (200,200,0), (100,200,5000)$ and got an absolute error $\delta_{error} \approx 2$. For some reason the cross product version doesn't suffer from this behavior.

Comment: @JeanMarie It think it also depends on the implementation and compiler options.

Answer (score 1):

I use cross products, but I convert it in coordinates afterwards, with minimum computations (in particular, there is no need to use matrices):

$$\text{area}=\frac12 \|\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}\|$$

Explanation: as $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ "live" in a 2D space, we have used here a 2D well known formula.

For a developed form with coordinates, if we set:

$$\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_B-x_A\\y_B-y_A\\z_B-z_A\end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_C-x_A\\y_C-y_A\\z_C-z_A\end{pmatrix} $$

$$\text{area}=\frac12 \sqrt{(u_2v_3-u_3v_2)^2+(u_3v_1-u_1v_3)^2+(u_1v_2-u_2v_1)^2}$$